# Digitally Signing InfoPath Forms

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, certificate, infopath

I have an InfoPath 2007 form with custom .NET code.  In order for it to be accessible on our Sharepoint server, it needs to run in full-trust (I get an error about the form trying to access my computer, and therefore it cannot run).  In order to run in full-trust, it needs to be signed with a cert.  The network admin sent me a cert, but it won't show up in the InfoPath "select certificate" dialog when I try to sign it, even after I installed the certificate on my machine.  I think it is because the certificate's purpose is server authentication, when it needs to be code signing.  Is there any way to use this certificate to sign the form?  Or for that matter is there another way to get the form to run on the server without being digitally signed?

Answer (score 2):

And because i'm new here is the second link...

and this is digging a little deeper on how to build and deploy full trust forms:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb251025.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is a couple of ways to get your form full trust. I dont mean to just post a link in here but this should get you going in the right direction.

this gives an over view:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb251022.aspx